# steps for use core data as database in my iOS app in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

anyone can describe me about core data?
I want to create worksheet which store day activity record and that data stored in local file.
I think core data is best to store locally.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of asking for steps on SO you should have spent the time Googling up Core Data Programming Guide or Tutorials. This is not the place to ask and receive tutorials. There are literally hundreds of materials on the web regarding Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

You should see CoreData not as a database, but as a way to manage a graph of object.

You can then store this graph in different places (transparently from the application point of view) such as memory, XML, sqlite, and I think custom binary file.

What you usually do is to write the model in a core data model.

Each object is either an instance of `NSManagedObject` (which you can query / work with with methods such as `valueForKey:`, `setValueForKey:` etc) or subclasses of that class. This subclasses can be autogenerated directly from Xcode, and at this point you almost forget you are working with CoreData. Every attribute is a `@property`, every to-many relationship is a `NSSet`. 
You get back to the fact that you are using CoreData when you create and want to save the object. In this case you have to get the 'context' in which the object resides, and call method on it (e.g. `save`)

There is full of tutorial and documentation on the web about CoreData.
In my opinion the core point is.. don't think at it as a relational database. "Be more object oriented" :)

To getting started you can take a look at:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

The for more complex stuff the apple doc is ok
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started is helpful for beginner in core data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, Core data is bast way to store data in iOS applications.

With new `XCode` all you need to do is when creating new project click check box that you will use coreData.

This will create `yourPorject.xcdatamodeld` file and some methods inside your `AppDelegate` file :

```
 - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
// The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "result.PingPong" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
 }

 - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
// The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PingPong" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
 }

 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
     // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
     if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

   // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"PingPong.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
 }


 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
     return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
 }

 #pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

 - (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
 }
```

(I case it didn't)

After that you create your entity object inside `yourPorject.xcdatamodeld`, by clicking on `AddEntity`, name it and inside with `Add Attribute` add all your attributes.

After that click on menu : Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclasses. This will automatically create object for you.

All you need to do to save object into database is

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

YourObject * o = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"YourObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
o.attribute1 = attribute1;
o.attribute2 = attribute2;

[context save:nil];
```

To fetch all object you will need this :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSError *fetchError;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
if (fetchError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error fetching database request. Reason: %@", fetchError);
}
```

I hope it will help you for start.

Marko

Comment: Using this i understand the flow of core data code.